# Error while connecting IBM Cognos 10.2.1 with Hive 0.11

Tags: jdbc, hive, cognos-10

I am trying to have Hive as a data source for Cognos 10.2.1. I am having Hive version 0.11. I placed the following Jars from the Hive server to Cognos 
Installation Directories (cognos_install_Directory\webapps\p2pd\WEB-INF\lib  and Cognos_Install_directory\v5dataserver\lib).

commons-logging-1.0.4

guava-11.0.2

hadoop-core-1.2.1

hive-common-0.11.0

hive-exec-0.11.0

hive-jdbc-0.11.0

hive-metastore-0.11.0

hive-service-0.11.0

libfb303-0.9.0

libthrift-0.9.0

log4j-1.2.16

slf4j-api-1.6.1

slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1

hive-beeline-0.11.0

httpcore-4.2.5

httpclient-4.2.5

I started HiveSserver2 and I went to Cognos connection to create Datasource. First I am giving name of the data source and selected jdbc as data source wizard. Then I am selecting Hive as a type in the connecting string property. 
I giving the following values to the connect string property like,
jdbc:hive2://Hive_Hostname:10000/database_name

and Driver name as

org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

I also gave username and password for this.

When I am try to test the connection I got the following error

```
Connection failed: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://172.17.13.63:10000/newdb: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
```

I don't know where I made mistake, I have very few material available in net. please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing listening on 172.17.13.63:10000 (or a firewall is blocking you).

Comment: Thanks for replying back to me, I checked the fire wall, It is inactive state in both Ubuntu and Windows as well

Answer (score 1):

The Actual problem here is I installed Cognos 10.2.1 version and there is no connectivity between this Cognos release and Hive 0.8 to 0.12 versions. But from the Cognos 10.2.1 fix pack 4 on-wards it is possible to connect these versions of Hive. So I upgraded Cognos 10.2.1 to its latest fix pack which is 11 and tried the connectivity. Now I can able to connect with this.